Not able to upload image data to firebase with tinymce
I'm trying to upload images to firebase storage, and it is working fine if a image is uploaded using the tinymce image button
Instead if I copy and paste the image or drag and drop it won't work.
This is what I'm trying
        images_upload_handler: async (blobInfo:any,  progress:any) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              let blob: Blob;
              let filename: string;
          
              blob = blobInfo.blob();
              filename = blobInfo.filename();

              const filePath = 'content/uploaded/images/lp/' + Date.now() + "-"+ filename;
              const storage = getStorage();
      

              const storageRef = ref(storage, filePath);
              
              const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef,blob);

              () => {
                // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                  resolve(downloadURL);
                });
              }
              );
            })
          },

